# Android Button to open xml layout

Tags: android, xml, button, navigation, switch-statement

Hi I'm very new to android development, and want to create an app with three pages and a main page with buttons on it navigating to the different pages. I have create the different xml pages and I believe I have to create some sort of onclick thing but im unsure.

What java code do I need, what else to I need to add to the normal button xml etc. can anyone please show me an example to implement into my work with pictures please

This is one of my buttons

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/information"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="#fff"
  android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
  android:text="Information  >"
  android:textSize="18dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
  />
```

This is the only java file I have (do i add to this or make new one)

```
package com.techie.layout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import reading.festival.guide.R;

public class LayoutPractice extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//makes full screen and takes away title bar
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
//

setContentView(R.layout.linear);
}

}
```

My other xml layouts are called sitemap, information, and lineup the original xml is called linear.

I hope I have provided enough information for someone to help me, im sure its very easy and im being stupid

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you say "pages" you mean Activities. You'll need to create an activity for each of your layout files.

Reading material:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach is to define the click handler in your xml using the `android:onClick` attribute:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/information"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="#fff"
  android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
  android:text="Information  >"
  android:textSize="18dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
  android:onClick="myClickHandler"
  />
```

By adding this, you are telling Android the name of a function within your Activity to call when your button is clicked.  This function has to follow few rules though.  It must have a return type of void, take only one argument which is a View.  Staying with the above example, you would need to add the following in your Activity, it would be:

```
public void myClickHandler(View v){
  //handle the click here
}
```

You will likely need to create separate Activities for your sitemap, information, and linuep layouts.  Don't forget to declare those new Activities in your manifest.xml too.

Lets say you create one called `InformationActivity`.  To launch it from our example button click, you would do this:

```
 public void myClickHandler(View v){
       startActivity(new Intent(this, InformationActivity.class);
    }
```

For more details, read about Activities and UI in the [Android dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html).

Comment: this sounds good and possibly what i am after but can you speak very slowly and and with as much info possible as you have just blown my mind but thanks (for instance where exactly do i put things ie files etc)

Comment: I've added some more details and a pointer to the android dev guide.  You should read through the dev guide to understand all of the basic concepts.  You might want to pick up an Android book too.  I'll be happy to answer specific questions you might have.

Comment: Thank you every so much for your help and very quick replies, can you tell me exactly where to create these activites etc im still unsure as where to put these snippets of codes

Comment: Each Activity is a separate class, just like LayoutPractice in your question for example.  You can put them in the same place as LayoutPractice.  The click handler functions can go anywhere within your Activity class.

Answer (score 1):

You should get button object into your code and add new ClickListener to it

```
Button infoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.information);
infoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        // here is your button click logic, for example running another activity (page)
        startActivity(new Intent(LayoutPractice.this, SiteMapActivity.class));
    }   
});
```

Hope this help.
PS. code may be wrong, wrote it from memory

Comment: this is helpful, however where would i place this pls

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

where the NewActivity is name of activity which you wants to render