# onClick start new activity android

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, action

I have a little problem with action bar item.
I want to create clicable item in action bar which opens new java activity.

ab_button_desktop is the custom button which I created.
I tried a lot java codes from tutorials and I havent still any resoults.
Could anyone recommend me java code which opens new activity.

This is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:webviewapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ab_button_desktop"
        android:title="@string/ab_button_desktop"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_desktop"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:onClick="desktop"
        webviewapp:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ab_button_share"
        android:title="@string/ab_button_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        webviewapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Comment: You need to handle menu click in your `Fragment` or `Activity`. Your `xml` can't just launch an activity.

Comment: I know that I cant lounch activity just with xml.I asked if someone could recommend me or write java code for this because I tried and it wasnt succesfull.I am not expirienced in java jet.

Answer (score 0):

By adding **android:onClick="desktop"**  you are telling Android the name of a function within your Activity to call when your button is clicked. This function has to follow few rules though. It must have a return type of void, take only one argument which is a View. To open a new Activity you would have to add the following code to your Activity where the button currently is:

```
public void desktop(View v){
  //handle the click here
}
```

Lets say you create one called InformationActivity. To launch it from example button click, you would do this:

```
 public void desktop(View v){
       startActivity(new Intent(this, InformationActivity.class);
    }
```

For more details, read about [Activities and UI in the Android dev guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Original Answer: [Android Button to open xml layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128274/android-button-to-open-xml-layout)

Comment: I put this code to MainActivity like this                                                                 public void Click(View menu_main){

        startActivity(new Intent(this, DesktopActivity.class));
    }                                                                                      and my app crashes when i start it

Comment: I hope that you created your DesktopActivity as Android Activity not just a *.class file.  Then, as I mentioned, your onClick is "desktop"  not "click"
I suggest that you start with a basic android tutorial online: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can handle clicks on menu items by overriding `OnOpionsItemSelectd`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getId()){
    case R.id.ab_button_desktop:
        //Do something
    break;
    case R.id.ab_button_share:
        //Do something else
    break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

For a tutorial on how to launch activities, click [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).